# What is the right way to enable contextual links on a field template with custom code?

Tags: drupal, theming

I'm trying to figure out if there a way to enable `contextual-links` on a field twig template using custom code. I have an entity reference field and created a field template`field--field-featured-page.html.twig` below is a code snippet for the field template.

After clearing the cache I can't seem to enable the contextual links.

[image]

```
<div class="related-links -home :three-column">

    {% for item in items  %}

        {% set entity = item.content['#options'].entity %}

        <div class="related-link">
            <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': entity.id})  }}" class="thumbnail -landscape" style="background-image:url({{ file_url(entity.field_image.entity.uri.value) }})">
            </a>
            <h2 class="preamble-heading" data-preamble="{{ entity.field_preamble.value }}">{{ entity.label }}</h2>

        </div>


    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

---

Below is a snippet of the markup for the `contextual-link`. Adding this markup and fetching the node ID might solve the problem but it seems to be hackish. What is the proper way to enable contextual-links on a field twig template?

```
{% set node_id = item.content['#options'].entity.id %} 

{# Contextual Links #}

<div data-contextual-id="node:node={{ node_id }}:&amp;langcode={{ lang_code }}" class="contextual contextual-button" role="form">
<button class="trigger focusable" type="button" aria-pressed="false"></button>

    <ul class="contextual-links" hidden="">
        <li class="entitynodeedit-form"><a href="{{ url('<front>') }}node/{{ node_id }}/edit">Edit</a></li>
        <li class="entitynodedelete-form"><a href="{{ url('<front>') }}node/{{ node_id }}/delete">Delete</a></li>
        <li class="content-translationcontextual-linksnode"><a href="{{ url('<front>') }}node/{{ node_id }}/translations">Translate</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

The code below is the template for a specific content type `(Basic Page)`

```
{{ page.header }}

<div {{attributes.addClass('iom-home')}}>
    {{ title_suffix }}




    {{ content.field_featured_page  }}




</div>

{{ page.footer }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this same issue -- seems like the contextual links are rendered by `{{ title_suffix }}` in each template. At least it seems to be the case for a block template. Not sure if it'll work for a field template.

So updating your snippet to the following might work (Assuming that it corresponds with the contents of your `field--field-featured-page.html.twig`):

```
<div class="related-links -home :three-column">

    {{ title_suffix }}

    {% for item in items  %}

        {% set entity = item.content['#options'].entity %}

        <div class="related-link">
            <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': entity.id})  }}" class="thumbnail -landscape" style="background-image:url({{ file_url(entity.field_image.entity.uri.value) }})">
            </a>
            <h2 class="preamble-heading" data-preamble="{{ entity.field_preamble.value }}">{{ entity.label }}</h2>

        </div>


    {% endfor %}
</div>
```